# Magento: how to display a different placeholder image for a product based on product attribute

Tags: php, magento

**Question:**
How can I customize Magento to use a different placeholder image for a product based on a particular product attribute?

More info:

- I understand that Magento uses a placeholder image if the product doesn't have any specific images
- But, I want the placeholder image to change based on a custom product attribute (e.g. part type)
- Magento community version:  1.7.0.2

For example:

- if product type is a hammer and no specific product image exists:

  - then I want the placeholder image to be a generic hammer image
- if product type is a screwdriver and no specific product image exists:

  - then I want the placeholder image to be a generic screwdriver image
- etc, for additional part types

Notes

- I don't want to default to the category image
- I don't want to have to upload the images to each product
- I just want to extend the placeholder functionality to provide a different image based on a product attribute

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the info from @Rob I created a working prototype.  Here is the patch for those that are interested:

First file

```
diff --git a/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php b/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
--- a/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
+++ b/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
@@ -349,7 +349,14 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
             if ($this->getImageFile()) {
                 $model->setBaseFile($this->getImageFile());
             } else {
-                $model->setBaseFile($this->getProduct()->getData($model->getDestinationSubdir()));
+                // if part type is in the passed product then use it otherwise get it
+                if ($this->getProduct()->getPartType()) {
+                    $productPartType = $this->getProduct()->getPartType();
+                } else {
+                    $productPartType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getPartType();
+                }
+
+                $model->setBaseFile($this->getProduct()->getData($model->getDestinationSubdir()), $productPartType);
             }

             if ($model->isCached()) {
```

Second file

```
diff --git a/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php b/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
--- a/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
+++ b/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
@@ -260,7 +260,7 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
      * @param string $file
      * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
      */
-    public function setBaseFile($file)
+    public function setBaseFile($file, $partType=Null)
     {
         $this->_isBaseFilePlaceholder = false;

@@ -278,10 +278,23 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
             }
         }
         if (!$file) {
+            // check if part type placeholder file exists
+            if ($partType) {
+                $skinPartTypeBaseDir     = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir();
+                $skinPartTypePlaceholder = "/images/catalog/product/placeholder/{$partType}.jpg";
+                $PartTypefile = $skinPartTypePlaceholder;
+            }
+
             // check if placeholder defined in config
             $isConfigPlaceholder = Mage::getStoreConfig("catalog/placeholder/{$this->getDestinationSubdir()}_placeholder");
             $configPlaceholder   = '/placeholder/' . $isConfigPlaceholder;
-            if ($isConfigPlaceholder && $this->_fileExists($baseDir . $configPlaceholder)) {
+
+            // Use part type placeholder image if it exists
+            if ($partType && file_exists($skinPartTypeBaseDir . $PartTypefile)) {
+                $baseDir = $skinPartTypeBaseDir;
+                $file = $PartTypefile;
+            }
+            elseif ($isConfigPlaceholder && $this->_fileExists($baseDir . $configPlaceholder)) {
                 $file = $configPlaceholder;
             }
             else {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get products' `parent category_id` by using below code

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
$ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryId = (isset($ids[0]) ? $ids[0] : null);
```

than you can have your custom `if/else` condition for displaying the placeholder image...

there should be one problem. **if a product have more than one parent category than what do you want??**

**UPDATE**

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

you can now use the same category logic for attribute as well...

Comment: Your answer does not address my question.  I don't care about the product category, because I want to change the placeholder image bases off of a product attribute.  but thanks anyway

Comment: ohh I am sorry... but same logic you can use for attributes as well. I am posting the code to get the `custom attribute value of the product`....

Comment: This still doesn't solve his main problem,  how do you determine whether or not the Magento Placeholder is being used? He only wants to use the secondary image if there isn't an existing product image.  The process would first involve checking for a place holder, and if found then check to see if there is an attribute value.

Comment: @Rob here is the answer :)... http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/how-to-check-if-product-image-added-or-place-holder-image-used/

Comment: Tested, doesn't work on category and product pages on Magento 1.8 and 1.9 the issue here if you check app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/image.php there's no way for this to return a null value by checking for the small image / thumbnail etc because it assigns the placeholder to the different image values prior this function being called.  It's more complicated than it seems,

Comment: @Rob you cant say that there is no way.. because if magento does it than there should be one way... my answer gives a way to the user for startup..

Comment: Well yes it can be done.  I had to extend this model to intercept the use of the placeholder.  if ($_product->getSmallImage()=='no_selection' ) // will only return true under rare  circumstances  i.e  product image is in a correct location but had its name changed directly in the file system. This may have been a valid method in older versions of Magento. The public function setBaseFile is the reason why your solution will not work.

Comment: @Rob and Nishant, I appreciate the activity...but I think you are still both a little off on my main goal.       I would like to customize the **code that is responsible for returning the placeholder image**.  Therefore, I don't have to change the phtml in every location that requests the placeholder image. I don't want to change the logic that determines if a placeholder is needed or not. The customized code would change the returned file based on the product attribute.          My problem is that I can't find the code that is responsible for resolving the image file name of the placeholder.

Comment: I am on the exact same page as you. You have to extend the image.php model. Specifically the function setBaseFile  setBaseFile controls the action as to when to use the Placeholder.  If I get some time, I can write an extension to do this. If you take a look at that function you will see what happens.  It looks for a file path, to use, then it will use the set image if not that it uses the placeholder.. If there is an image it then checks for enough memory to render the image.  if not than it resorts back to the placeholder.  This is where the intercept will need to take place.

Comment: @Rob thanks.  You pointed me in the right direction with your reference to setBaseFile, and I was able to get a prototype working.  I also had to modify `__toString()` of the class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` to pass the desired product attribute, since setBaseFile() doesn't have a reference to the product (or at least I couldn't find it).